# Bad precision in GeoLocation in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a Google Map (v3) on a website. When a user hits the page, I am reading the geolocation from it´s browser (if it´s supported):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeOut, maximumAge: maximumAge })
```

The function is working, but not always as expected. In Google Chrome it´s working perfectly - the **`getCurrentPosition`** function is returning a coordinate object with latitude and longitude as floating points (decimals). Curiously it´s different in IE11. It´s also returning the coordinate object - but here are both latitude and longitude in integers, which means, that the accuracy is very bad, and not really showing the right position on the map.

Is this a bug? And does anyone know if it´s possible to fix this?

Thank you in advance!
/Thomas

Comment: Try setting [`enableHighAccuracy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg593067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ENABLEHIGHACCURACY) to `true`

Comment: @Andreas
As you can see, I already do that :(

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked the setting... :(